# How to show rating of a provider with stars

Tags: ios, rating

Hi guys I have a list of providers in my UITableView and want to show their rating with stars.
I have an Image with 5 stars and and Integer from 1-10 from my XML. Every 1 Integer should fill a half of a star with blue color.
I hope you forgive me for the bad english and help me out, Thanks.

It should look like this. The difference is that I want to fill the color of the stars from XML Strings not from user touch.

http://just-works.blogspot.in/2012/12/ahsstarrating-for-ios.html

Comment: Please provide fiddle or code.

Comment: I editted my question, hope it's more clear now

Comment: I would suggest using a css sprite. Depending on the value of your "string" adjust the background accordingly. Need to see some code, not going do this for you.

Comment: hmm, and set the position of the sprites, so they are next to each other?

Comment: A sprite is a single image, so it would be a very long image.

I would use this: http://playarentalproperties.com/~playaren/components/com_jomholiday/templates/default/assets/rating/images/stars_large_sprite.jpg

Every time the value of your "string" changes, just adjust the background of the stars up or down a few pixels to reflect the proper rating.

Comment: Ok seems logic i'll test it, thanks @Mark

Comment: Consider open source component for this too eg.: https://github.com/dlinsin/DLStarRating     OR      https://github.com/erndev/EDStarRating

Comment: I made use of @Marks Answer, it worked fine. Thanks

Comment: @Mark it worked fine, could upvote if you copy it as answer! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sprite is a single image, so it would be a very long image. I would use this: playarentalproperties.com/~playaren/components/com_jomholiday/… Every time the value of your "string" changes, just adjust the background of the stars up or down a few pixels to reflect the proper rating.